# Preflight OPTIONS request on same-origin

Tags: php, http

Is there a scenario in which a client would make an preflight OPTION request, even though the domains are the same so the cross origin policy shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Http pages requesting https ajax will be cross domain, and cause an option request.